# Cannot code prepend logger correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, console

I have this simple function which will prepend a desired string to the beginning of each line. I have this working with streams, but in some cases it's also convenient using a console.log() type of construct.

Here is the function:

// takes a string to prepend, and a stream to prepend to:

```
exports.lp = function (str, strm) {
    return function prependLog() {
        var args = Array.from(arguments);
        var hasNonWhitespace = args.some(function (a) {
            var str = String(a);
            return str.length > 0 && /\S/g.test(str);
        });
        if (hasNonWhitespace) {
            strm.write(str);
        }
        args.forEach(function (s, i) {
            String(s).split('\n').forEach(function (s, i) {
                if (i < 1) {
                    strm.write(s + ' ');
                }
                else {
                    strm.write('\n' + str + s);
                }
            });
        });
        strm.write('\n');
    };
};
```

Here is the use:

```
const {lp} = require('log-prepend');
const fn = lp(' [foobar] ', process.stdout);


fn('\n');
fn();
fn();
fn('','','');
fn('log1', 'log2\n3',4,5 + '\n55');
fn('a','b','c');
```

and here is the output from the above:

```
 [foobar] 



 [foobar] log1 log2 
 [foobar] 34 5 
 [foobar] 55
 [foobar] a b c
```

the problem is that for empty lines with no non-whitespace character, it usually works, but when I include a newline character, it outputs [foobar] even though there is nothing on that line.

I can't figure out why my function doesn't omit `[foobar]` for lines with no non-whitespace. So to be exact, it is the first instance of `[foobar]` above that is mystifying me.

Answer (score 1):

Having a little trouble following the logic here but is it because you are expecting to use the index variable from the first forEach function, when it's actually using it from the second? Renaming the initial variables might help.

Comment: I made a fix, it works as expected now. Still looking for perhaps a more efficient or robust way to code it.

Comment: You can test it yourself to see if it behaves exactly like `console.log()` or `console.error()` but with the given prepending string on each line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a good fix like so:

```
exports.lp = function (str, strm) {
    return function prependLog() {
        var args = Array.from(arguments);
        var hasNonWhitespace = args.some(function (a) {
            var str = String(a);
            return str.length > 0 && /\S/g.test(str);
        });
        if (hasNonWhitespace) {
            strm.write(str);
        }
        args.forEach(function (s, i) {
            String(s).split('\n').forEach(function (s, i) {
                if (i < 1) {
                    strm.write(s + ' ');
                }
                else {

                  // => here is the fix, add the following if/else

                 if (/\S/g.test(s)) {
                    strm.write('\n' + str + s);
                 }
                 else {
                    strm.write('\n' + s);
                 }
                }
            });
        });
        strm.write('\n');
    };
};
```

but if anyone has a better way to do this, please let me know.